# Looking to assign a value to a variable at the time of declaring it

Tags: basic4android

In VB you can both define and assign a value to a variable in one line.

Can you do this in Basic4Android?

VB code sample:

```
Dim strMyVariable As String = "Some text is in here"
```

Update:
I tried this and got the following error:

```
NumberOfColumns As Int = 5  ' Number of columns.

Compiling code.                         Error
Error compiling program.
Error description: '=' expected.
Occurred on line: 13
NumberOfColumns As Int = 5' Number of columns.
Word: numberofcolumns
```

Update:

```
Compiling code.                         Error
Error compiling program.
Error description: Syntax error.
Occurred on line: 13
Dim NumberOfColumns As Int = 5 ' Number of columns.
Word: int
```

Comment: Did you try it? If so, post the code that isn't working.

Comment: Hi Polynomial, Yes I did try it. I made an update to the post to show what I did.

Comment: Ooops silly me. I forgot the Dim statement.

Comment: As soon as I put in the Dim statement I get a different error. The new error is shown in the update section of the post.

Comment: My VB is a little rusty (I'm mainly dealing with C# these days) but I think it should be `As Integer` rather than `As Int`.

Comment: @Polynomial, this isn't VB, it's Basic4Android. `Int` is correct. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAICT, you can't.

If you really feel you need to do it on the same line, you can do it like this:

```
Dim NumberOfColumns As Int: NumberOfColumns = 5
```

The colon is defined in the user's guide (page 111) as the "separator for two statements on the same line".